# How to check if an argument has a single character in shell

Tags: shell, grep, arguments, character

I'm trying to make a script to check if an argument has a single uppercase or lowecase letter,   or if its anything else (a digit or a word for example.)

So far got this done:

```
if echo $1 | egrep -q '[A-Z]';
    then echo "Uppercase";
elif echo $1 | egrep -q '[a-z]';
    then echo "Lowercase";
else
    echo "FAIL";
fi
```

Need to make it to fail me not only if it isnt a letter, but if I insert a word or 2 letters.

Comment: Thanks for your clear & well formatted question. Good start for a new coming. =)

Comment: Good work on your first question! Haven't seen too many of those. :) I'm afraid I don't know the answer to your question though. :(

Comment: What is your shell? Is it bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You was very close !

```
if echo $1 | egrep -q '^[A-Z]$';
    then echo "Uppercase";
elif echo $1 | egrep -q '^[a-z]$';
    then echo "Lowercase";
else
    echo "FAIL";
fi
```

- I've just added the special characters `^` & `$`, means respectively *start of line* & *end of line*
- no need `egrep` there, `grep` is sufficient

Comment: This is embarrasing Q.Q should have got to this by myself. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Note that this fails if `$1` contains a newline.

Answer (score 2):

Use `case`:

```
case "$1" in
    [a-z]) echo First argument is a lower case letter;;
    [A-Z]) echo First argument is an upper case letter;;
    *) echo First argument is not a single letter;;
esac
```

Comment: Cant use Case yet, Teacher's demanded so... Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash,

```
if [[ $1 == [[:upper:]] ]]; then
    echo "$1 is a single capital letter"
elif [[ $1 == [[:lower:]] ]]; then
    echo "$1 is a single lowercase letter"
else
    echo "$1 is not a letter or is more than 1 char"
fi
```

The double equals tells bash to match against a pattern on the right-hand side.

Comment: Yeah that works too, but the thing is that it has to know wether it is upper or lower, and show it.